# Formatting to only alphanumerical including unicode characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have this script

```
key = val.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '+')
```

It works fine, but it also takes out unicode characters such as `აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ`

My question is how can I change a given code so that it will accept these characters as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first `replace` specifically replaces everything which is not an English alphabet letter, a digit, or whitespace with the empty string. Since The Georgian letters are none of those then they are being replaced. You need to add the Georgian letters into your first regex too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript regular expressions don't support unicode properties. You have to add explicit unicode ranges to your expression. For example, the range for Georgian is 10A0-10FF, so to replace everything that is not a Latin or Georgian character, you need something like

```
val.replace(/[^\w\u10A0-\u10FF]/g, '')
```

[This tool](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) can help you further.

Comment: thanks man, i'll accept it as soon as it will permit me to do so.

Comment: @Lindrian: that page appears to use php (PCRE) regexps rather than javascript's.

Comment: @thg435: Sorry, that is entirely my fault. I missed you only wanted to work with javascript and I am unsure if js supports the `\p`-construct. Regardless it's a nifty site to have at hand :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify allowed characters ranges manually, or you can use some library like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/).